# Does $2x+1 \mid 3y+2$ , $2y+1 \mid 3x+2$ have a solution for $x,y > 0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This is just a personal conjecture of mine (I couldn't find anything similar here):

> Does system of divisions $2x+1 \mid 3y+2$ and $2y+1 \mid 3x+2$ have a solution for integers $x,y > 0$?

It's clear it has a solution for $x=y=0$, but I'm struggling to find any solution for $x,y>0$ or prove that there is none.

What I tried was search through Maple and haven't found any solution. I tried to prove there is no solution, but couldn't make basically any progress apart from figuring out an obvious things... (such as that neither $2x+1$ nor $2y+1$ can be divisible by $3$, etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $2x + 1 < 3y + 2$ and $2y + 1 < 3x + 2$. Then, by divisibility,
$$2x + 1 \le (3y + 2)/2 = 1.5y + 1,$$
so $x \le 0.75y$, while similarly $y \le 0.75x$ by symmetry. Impossible!

Hence one of these inequalities doesn't hold, say $2x + 1 = 3y + 2$. Then $x = (3y+1)/2$, so you have
$$2y + 1 \mid 3x + 2 = (9y+7)/2,$$
or $4y + 2 \mid 9y + 7$. But $9y + 7 \equiv y + 3$ (mod $4y + 2$), and the latter can't be $0$ (mod $4y + 2$). So we have a contradiction, and there are no solutions.

Comment: Nice, that was quick! How did I miss that... btw I think it should be $2x + 1 \leq (3y + 2)/2$ for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!